# Sending an HTTP request with an imported WSDL with the string 'http://0X'

Tags: httprequest, wsdl2apex, httppost

I have a WSDL that i consume imported as an Apex class. One of the methods receives one String param that is the account website, and one of our users inserted a website that starts with 'http://06'. This caused a System.CalloutException with the return of the method being the http request failure page. After some research i came to the conclusion that any string that contains the sequence of characters 'http://0X' causes the same error. Can anyone provide an explanation for the occurring of this error?

Edit:

This is a standard wsdl2apex import but here is the code that it generates:

My method:

```
public class myWSDL {
    public class myMethod_element {
        public myWSDL.MyInnerClass myStructure;
        private String[] myStructure_type_info = new String[]{'myStructure','https://www.endpoint.com/pt/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'https://www.endpoint.com/pt/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'myStructure'};
    }
    public class MyInnerClass {
        public String myString;
        private String[] myString_type_info = new String[]{'myString','https://www.endpoint.com/pt/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'https://www.endpoint.com/pt/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'myString'};
    }

    public class MyResult {
        public String result;
        private String[] result_type_info = new String[]{'result','https://www.endpoint.com/pt/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'https://www.endpoint.com/pt/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'result'};
    }
    public class myMethodResponse_element {
        public myWSDL.MyResult myResult;
        private String[] myResultResult_type_info = new String[]{'myResult','https://www.endpoint.com/pt/',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'https://www.endpoint.com/pt/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'myResult'};
    }
    public class MySoapBinding {
        public String endpoint_x = 'https://www.endpoint.com/';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'https://www.endpoint.com/pt/', 'myWSDL'};

        public myWSDL.MyResult myMethod(myWSDL.MyInnerClass myStructure) {
            myWSDL.myMethod_element request_x = new myWSDL.myMethod_element();
            request_x.myStructure = myStructure;
            myWSDL.myMethodResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, myWSDL.myMethodResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, myWSDL.myMethodResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(this,
                                     request_x,
                                     response_map_x,
                                     new String[]{endpoint_x,
                                         'https://www.endpoint.com/pt/myMethod',
                                         'https://www.endpoint.com/pt/',
                                         'myMethod',
                                         'https://www.endpoint.com/pt/',
                                         'myMethod',
                                         'myWSDL.myMethodResponse_element'
                                         });
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');

            return response_x.myResult;
        }
    }
}
```

And how it is called:

```
myWSDL.MyInnerClass req = new myWSDL.MyInnerClass();
req.myString= 'http://06';//EXAMPLE
myWSDL.MyResult result = new myWSDL.MySoapBinding().myMethod(req);
```

And the result exception when i attemp to call it:

```
00:00:00:000 EXCEPTION_THROWN [X]|System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':html'
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the apex method? Without seeing it, it'll be hard to determine exactly whats going wrong.

Comment: Added the code. Hope it helps. This is a simple HTTPRequest call made from an imported WSDL with the wsdl2apex tool. The problem is, when one of the string parameters goes with that string, it throws that exception.